# Illustrator: How can you interlock chain links when each chain link is above and under another?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, 3d

I've tried all afternoon to create these thick black (which will be 3D) interlocking chain links and have had no success. I've tried recreating the chains in pieces, I tried using the scissor tool, but every time when I make it 3D, the main problem is that each link in the chain is both in front of, then underneath the other links next to it.

How do I create this realistic interweaving effect?

Do I have to pick a different software? I have all the suite, so I can do that, but all the tutorials I watched today were a total waste of time, they didn't give me answers for this 3D spatial problem.

[image: Interlocking chain links]

Comment: Too short on time here to post a proper answer but if Scott's answer doesn't work, opacity masks might

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way for me to create interlocking shapes is to use the **Shape Builder Tool** --- [image]

Select the artwork and with the **Shape Builder Tool** click-drag to combine sections. 
Hold down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key and click-drag to remove sections.

[image]  [image]

Comment: Wow, Scott, that's perfect. That is exactly what I needed. I can't thank you enough.